# Use fs.unlinkSync with full path to remove file in project, it works on local server, but it gives error(5xx) after deployed to azure web app

Tags: networking, azure-web-app-service, filesystems

I have an app that builds with Vuejs and Nodejs server.

I created a folder called 'uploads' in the project to temporary store all of the files that was uploaded to the server.

When the uploaded action is ready, I have a restAPI to clean the file in folder 'uploads' with the given absolute path. I use fs.unlinkSync to remove the temp file in the rest api.

Everything works perfectly on local, but after I deploy to azure web app, whenever the restapi for removing a file is triggered, it gives me 502 bad gateway error.

I have checked a lot of information, still can not solve this problem. Wonder if anyone have experience with it?

**Log from Azure Web App**
Failed to forward request to application. Encountered a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception after 300196.724ms with message: The operation was canceled.. Check application logs to verify the application is properly handling HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `fs.unlink(path, callback)`, then you can log more error details in callback function.

## **Suggestion**

1. You also can use `try..catch...` to get more exception message. Get error details should be useful to you to solve the problem.

   About `Log from Azure Web App`, I'm not sure how you use it, or use the default. The exception caught by the code may be more helpful to you.
2. If you use linux platform, you can use remote debugging.

   [Azure Remote Debugging for Node.js](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/remote-debugging)

Comment: it works with fs.unlink(). But I had to ask Azure support for the 502 gateway issue